# Is there a way to convert DMA codes into lat/longs?

Tags: python, pandas, data-conversion, dma

I am trying to figure out a way to get the center of a DMA code and turn it into lat/longs, using python/pandas. Please let me know if any of you have an idea on how to go about this, thank you!!

Comment: Do you have the DMA codes mapped to a city? Can you provide a sample of the data you currently have?

Comment: There's "Major US Cities with Latitude/Longitude and DMA Codes" at https://gist.github.com/sillypog/4080120

Comment: I have no idea if the data there's correct or if the coordinates represent the center.